# Unable to suppress DeprecationWarning in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, warnings

I'm using scikit-learn on a supercomputer. I'm using the presently installed versions of the packages I need, and it works just fine. I have a local copy of the code for development.

Due to some apparent discrepancy in the sklearn and numpy versions on the system, I get the following warnings:

```
python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py:4: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
  from collections import Sequence
python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py:29: DeprecationWarning: numpy.core.umath_tests is an internal NumPy module and should not be imported. It will be removed in a future NumPy release.
  from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d
```

I don't need to see this warning or fix anything because I'm not developing anything on this system, I just need it to run. But if I use this code in production mode, I am going to get this warning in my error file **millions** of times and I won't be able to find any errors that actually matter.

In my python scripts I have:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
import numpy as np
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn import metrics
```

in my bash script I have:

```
jsrun -n $2 python3 -W ignore::DeprecationWarning myscript.py $args &
```

I've read a lot of the answers to similar questions but I don't see why I'm still getting this warning. How can I make it go away?

Comment: I wonder if you're having issues because of this extra `jsrun` layer. Are you able to run your python program on a single test node directly (i.e., without `jsrun`)? What happens if  you run the following: `python3.7 -c"from collections import Sequence; print('hello')"` and `python3.7 -Wignore -c"from collections import Sequence; print('hello')"`?

Comment: Hmm good point. I think there is something about the system where I'm supposed to be using jsrun, but I can restrict it 1 node. ```jsrun -n 1 python3.7 -c"from collections import Sequence; print('hello')"``` gives me the error, while ```jsrun -n 1 python3.7 -W ignore -c"from collections import Sequence; print('hello')"``` does not. Same with -n 2.

Comment: It seems like this is happening because for example, Sequence is being imported by sklearn, not by my script directly, and there's no warnings filter line in the sklearn code. But shouldn't the -W ignore flag take care of that?

Comment: Reading the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/warnings.html), I agree that the -W option _should_ also apply to imported modules. This is what makes me think that somehow the -W option is not being properly passed into the other nodes. The documentation also indicates that you can check `sys.warnoptions` in your code to verify this; maybe that is worth a try. Maybe IBM support can help as well (google indicates this is where the `jsrun` utility comes from)?

Comment: good suggestion...I dropped sys.warnoptions in several places in my script and I'm getting ['ignore'] back from all of them, from all the nodes. So it seems like it should work. I thought this was a python issue but maybe it's a system-specific issue.